# Web scraping a simulator content

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data inside simulators from websites, but I'm stuck on one of them. I'm not able to get the JSON structure.

This is what I've tried:

```py
import requests

url_puzzle = 'https://puzzle.pt/scripts/ITSector_Simulator.js?'
headers_puzzle = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'} 

response_puzzle = requests.get(url_puzzle, headers=headers_puzzle).json()
```

What I want is to get the TAN, TAEG, MTIC... that the simulator returns or the whole JSON structure that is fed to the simulator.

Comment: Check the network tab, observe what sort of request I'd the simulator is sending and most importantly at what url, what's are the parameters, them you manually send request at that url and get the data which is same as in the simulator.

Comment: Hmmm I can't find the parameters or the complete url to do it manually :(

Comment: It's a js file.What are you expecting to get from that? Looking at the js it seems to all be functions and the like for some other page to use in order to manipulate content (for example perform certain calculations using supplied function definitions). What is the webpage url that uses this js file?

Comment: @QHarr from this webpage (https://puzzle.pt/pt), I want to get the TAN, TAEG, MTIC... for a given set of values of the simulator. I think I would have to use POST with the parameters to return this info but I don't know how

Comment: Do you wish to change the values of Escolher o montante  and Definir o prazo etc?

Comment: Looks like the page uses https://puzzle.pt/scripts/ITSector_Simulator.js?  to source what is needs to perform the calculations to update the output values. Selenium might be a good option.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, for example, if I select "Escolher o montante" = 3000€ and "Definir o prazo" = "40 meses" then I want to get the result of MTIC, TAN, TAEG and Prestação Mensal

Answer (score 0):

A long winded way would be to click the +/- to achieve your target values. This uses selenium. You could try sendKeys to `amount` and `days` webElements rather than clicking.

e.g.

```
amount.clear()
amount.send_keys(escolher_o_montante)
days.clear()
days.send_keys(definir_o_prazo)
```

I can't test this at present. You may need to add the ' €' and ' meses'. Unsure as can't test if that option would even work.

Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

url = 'https://puzzle.pt/pt'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.maximize_window()
escolher_o_montante = 2000
definir_o_prazo = 40
marcar_o_dia_dos_pagamentos = 1 #24

amount = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#simAmountInput')
days = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#simDaysInput')
up_amount = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#amountSlider + .slider-plus')
down_amount = d.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-for=amountSlider].slider-minus')
up_days = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#deadlineSlider + .slider-plus')
down_days = d.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-for="amountSlider"].slider-minus')
one = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#day38')
twenty_four = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#day52')
amount.clear()

while amount.get_attribute('value').replace(' €','') != escolher_o_montante:
    current_amount = amount.get_attribute('value').replace(' €','')
    if int(current_amount) > escolher_o_montante: down_amount.click()
    if int(current_amount) < escolher_o_montante: up_amount.click()

while days.get_attribute('value').replace(' meses','') != definir_o_prazo:
    current_days = days.get_attribute('value').replace(' €','')
    if int(current_days) > definir_o_prazo: down_days.click()
    if int(current_days) < definir_o_prazo: up_days.click()

if marcar_o_dia_dos_pagamentos == 1:
    one.click()
else if marcar_o_dia_dos_pagamentos == 24:
    twenty_four.click()
else:
    print('invalid option')

mtic = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#TotalvalueToReturn').text
tan = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#TanValue').text
taeg = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#TAEGValue').text
prestação_mensal = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#MonthlyValueToReturn').text
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I believe that I'm having a problem with the cookies message... the code opens the website and then it freezes. I believe that it is waiting to select "Ok" in the cookies message. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Yes. Examine the html of the cookies banner. Find the accept element and click it.

Comment: d.find_element_by_css_selector("#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept").click()